# Смайлики в чат

Tags: php

как отсюда сделать много смайликов:

```
$string = $message;
$pattern = "=)";
$replacement = "<img src=\"/smile/happy.gif\">";

$text = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Есть один, а нужно много ^^

Comment: функция array() знакома?

Comment: такa array('=)',':D');

Answer (score 1):

Например, как-то так:

```
$smiles = array(
    "=)" => "happy",
    "=(" => "sad"
);
foreach($smiles as $k => &$v) {
    $v = sprintf('<img src="/smile/%s.gif" alt="%s">', $v, $k);
}

$text = strtr($string, $smiles);
```

Пример: http://ideone.com/XjW2D

Comment: Я убрал вызов `htmlspecialchars()` (осталось по ссылке на ideone) — в том месте, куда я вставил, он не нужен. Но Вы не забудьте `$string` им заранее обработать.

Answer (score 0):

Я тут занимаюсь разработкой сервера мгновенных сообщения. Функционал очень похож на функционал чата. Все смайлики появляются после регистрации, заведении своей странички( не реклама ). Так вот я реализовал на данный момент в системе порядка 70 смайлов. Вот, посмотри: http://litethings.16mb.com/

Comment: Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/userlists/123qweasdzxc_posted.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/u258298021/public_html/posted.php on line 7

Зачем вообще нужен этот сайт? ковырялся 10 минут и ничего не нашел. а сайт вроде как должен сообщения куда-то отправлять."Ваша страница" тут вообще раз на раз открывается меню.

Comment: А это как понимать подключение  библиотек до открытия хтмл тэга + кодировки нету заданной - из-за чего все кракозябликами :)))